# Django Form, how to get further model info for ModelChoiceField

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I have 3 models that are related to eachother. A showing has the 'film' and 'screen' foreignkeys that link to Film and Screen. I'm trying to setup a webpage so that you can view information on a showing that is already setup, and edit it from dropdowns of what films and screens are available.

The problem I have at the moment is that instead of showing the screen numbers, and film titles that can be selected from, my dropdowns are showing 'Screen Object (4)' or 'Film Object (2)'. How do I get that next level of information to show from each object?

My models are:

```
class Film(models.Model):
    ageRatings =[
        ("U", "U"),
        ("PG", "PG"),
        ("12", "12"),
        ("15", "15"),
        ("18", "18"),
    ]

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    length = models.DurationField()
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=ageRatings, default="U")
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    poster_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    
    
class Screen(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    cinema = models.ForeignKey(Cinema, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='screens')
    screen_number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    seating_capacity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    

class Showing(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    film = models.ForeignKey(Film, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='showings')
    screen = models.ForeignKey(Screen, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='showings')
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    available_seats = models.IntegerField()
    adult_price = models.FloatField()
    student_price = models.FloatField()
    child_price = models.FloatField()
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.end_time = self.start_time + self.film.length
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        out = self.start_time.strftime("%d %B %Y %I:%M%p")
        out = out + " - " + self.film.title
        print(out)
        return out
```

My form is:

```
class ShowingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    screen = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Screen.objects.all().order_by('screen_number'))
    film = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Film.objects.all().order_by('title'))
    class Meta:
        model = Showing
        fields = ['screen', 'film', 'start_time']
```

My HTML is:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container mt-4">
  <h1>Update Showing</h1>
  <form method="post" action="{% url 'update_showing' showing.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        {{ field }}
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Showing</button>
  </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django searches for the string representation of `Screen` and `Film`. You have to define it the same way you did for `Showing` by implementing the `__str__()` method. Then this representation is going to replace "Screen Object (4)"

```py
class Film(models.Model):
    ageRatings =[
        ("U", "U"),
        ("PG", "PG"),
        ("12", "12"),
        ("15", "15"),
        ("18", "18"),
    ]

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    length = models.DurationField()
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=ageRatings, default="U")
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    poster_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
    
class Screen(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    cinema = models.ForeignKey(Cinema, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='screens')
    screen_number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    seating_capacity = models.PositiveIntegerField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.screens.name  # adjust this to your the logic of Cinema model
```